# What should I use as a reference file for clumping?

Tags: plink

I'm new to using PLINK and I have 2 basic questions about clumping. I'm computing polygenic risk scores for psychiatric diseases and will be using the following command to clump:

```
plink --noweb --bfile --clump hapmap --clump inputfile --clump-field P --clump-p1 --clump-p2 --clump-r2 --clump-kb
```

My first question: What type of file should I be using for the reference? Is it a map file?

My second question: How do I choose the most appropriate reference file?